# How to reposition widget without rebuilding its children in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

In my Flutter project, I want to reposition a list on a screen, using the `Positioned` widget, so the user can move the list manually or by using an animation.

What I did works pretty well, but I found out that, every time the list is moved, each item of the list is rebuild, which leads to some performance issues.

Here is a basic example:

```
class TestPositionedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPositionedPageState createState() => _TestPositionedPageState();
}

class _TestPositionedPageState extends State<TestPositionedPage> {

  double _yPage = 0;

  Widget _getItem(int position) {
    print("get item at $position");
    return ListTile(title: Text("Item at position $position"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() => _yPage = Random().nextDouble() * 500);
                },
                child: Text("MOVE"),
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              top: _yPage,
              child: Container(
                width: 700,
                height: 700,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) => _getItem(position),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In that example, there is a button and every time I click on the button, it randomly repositions the list. But every time the list is repositioned, here is what I see in the console:

```
I/flutter (17851): get item at 0
I/flutter (17851): get item at 1
I/flutter (17851): get item at 2
I/flutter (17851): get item at 3
I/flutter (17851): get item at 4
I/flutter (17851): get item at 5
I/flutter (17851): get item at 6
I/flutter (17851): get item at 7
I/flutter (17851): get item at 8
I/flutter (17851): get item at 9
I/flutter (17851): get item at 10
I/flutter (17851): get item at 11
I/flutter (17851): get item at 12
I/flutter (17851): get item at 13
I/flutter (17851): get item at 14
I/flutter (17851): get item at 15
I/flutter (17851): get item at 16
```

Which means that every time the list is repositioned, it's also rebuilt, even though nothing changed in the list.

So my question is: is there a way to prevent each item from being rebuilt every time the list is repositioned, **or** is there a way to cache the list rendering, in order to improve performances while repositioning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setState(() => _yPage = Random().nextDouble() * 500);` the whole tree is rebuilt again, which causing the list rebuilt too. Instead build the list one time and reuse required.

```
Widget _myList;
  
  Widget initList(){
   return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) => _getItem(position),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myList = initList();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Then use the list in this way

```
Positioned(
    left: 0,
    top: _yPage,
    child: Container(
        width: 700,
        height: 700,
        child: _myList
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That said, after some test, it doesn't improve the performances, and I might have some issues if I rotate the screen, for example if I use `MediaQuery.of(context)` in the `initList()` function... Any idea?

Comment: What kind of performance issues you having ?

Comment: When I use a `GestureDetector` widget to move the list with pan events, the frame rate is about 24 fps, which is quite bad (not terrible, but still far from the expected 60 fps...)

Comment: Assuming you tried in debug mode.  What about release mode?

Comment: Nope, that in release mode (well, profile mode, actually)... But I continue to investigate, the problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: my bad, the problem was elsewhere: a CustomPainter that calls paint() on each frame. Don't know why though, but it's another subject.